# Remembering Points with Google Maps Geometry

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a plugin for Google Maps Geometry called [GeoPortal](http://maps.co.mecklenburg.nc.us/geoportal/) to work our measurements on the roof of buildings.

I've got the plugin working fine into my application, it picks up on the Longitude and Latitude of a previous page where they are dynamically created from an entered address.

The issue I am having is that people need to be able to navigate backwards and forwards through the application, meaning that the area plot needs to be remembered, so when they navigate back to that page they will not have to redraw the area every time.

In example I need to remember this plot layout for when the person navigates back to the page:

[image]

*My code is as follows:*

**jQuery**

```
var map;

var measure = {
    mvcLine: new google.maps.MVCArray(),
    mvcPolygon: new google.maps.MVCArray(),
    mvcMarkers: new google.maps.MVCArray(),
    line: null,
    polygon: null
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 21,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.502378,-0.114348),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        draggableCursor: "crosshair" 
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(evt) {
        measureAdd(evt.latLng);
    });

});


function measureAdd(latLng) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latLng,
        draggable: true,
        raiseOnDrag: false,
        title: "Drag me to change shape",
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.co.mecklenburg.nc.us/geoportal/img/measure-vertex.png", new google.maps.Size(9, 9), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(5, 5))
    });

    measure.mvcLine.push(latLng);
    measure.mvcPolygon.push(latLng);

    measure.mvcMarkers.push(marker);

    var latLngIndex = measure.mvcLine.getLength() - 1;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
        marker.setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.co.mecklenburg.nc.us/geoportal/img/measure-vertex-hover.png", new google.maps.Size(15, 15), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(8, 8)));
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
        marker.setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.co.mecklenburg.nc.us/geoportal/img/measure-vertex.png", new google.maps.Size(9, 9), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(5, 5)));
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "drag", function(evt) {
        measure.mvcLine.setAt(latLngIndex, evt.latLng);
        measure.mvcPolygon.setAt(latLngIndex, evt.latLng);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
        if (measure.mvcLine.getLength() > 1) {
            measureCalc();
        }
    });

    if (measure.mvcLine.getLength() > 1) {

        if (!measure.line) {

            measure.line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                map: map,
                clickable: false,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 3,
                path:measure. mvcLine
            });

        }

        if (measure.mvcPolygon.getLength() > 2) {

            if (!measure.polygon) {

                measure.polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    clickable: false,
                    map: map,
                    fillOpacity: 0.25,
                    strokeOpacity: 0,
                    paths: measure.mvcPolygon
                });

            }

        }

    }

    if (measure.mvcLine.getLength() > 1) {
        measureCalc();
    }

}

function measureCalc() {

    var length = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(measure.line.getPath());
    jQuery("#span-length").text(length.toFixed(1))

    if (measure.mvcPolygon.getLength() > 2) {
        var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(measure.polygon.getPath());
        jQuery("#span-area").text(area.toFixed(1));
        document.getElementById('RoofArea').value = area.toFixed(1); 
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
    }


}

function measureReset() {

    if (measure.polygon) {
        measure.polygon.setMap(null);
        measure.polygon = null;
    }
    if (measure.line) {
        measure.line.setMap(null);
        measure.line = null
    }

    measure.mvcLine.clear();
    measure.mvcPolygon.clear();

    measure.mvcMarkers.forEach(function(elem, index) {
        elem.setMap(null);
    });
    measure.mvcMarkers.clear();

    jQuery("#span-length,#span-area").text(0);
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;

}
```

**HTML/CSS**

```
<style>
    #map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border: 5px solid #2F4B9E;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <p>Length (red line): <span id="span-length">0</span> mt<br />
    Area (grey area): <span id="span-area">0</span> mt&sup2;<br /> 
    <a href="javascript:measureReset();">Reset Measure</a></p>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwhmJ/1/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually answered my own question, so for the sake of closing this question, I'll post my solution here. I've used ColdFusion too.

In the `measureAdd()` function, I added this block of code below 
`measure.mvcMarkers.push(marker);`

```
var toJSON = JSON.stringify(latLng);
var toOutput = $.parseJSON(toJSON);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "panels_plot.cfc",
        data: {
            method: "setLatLon",
            theLat: toOutput.$a,
            theLon: toOutput.ab
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

which posted to this .cfc I created

```
<cfcomponent>
  <cffunction name="setLatLon" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="theLat" type="any" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="theLon" type="any" required="yes">
    <cfif NOT IsDefined('SESSION.latLon')>
        <cfset SESSION.latLon = ArrayNew(1)> 
    </cfif>
    <cfset st = StructNew()> 
    <cfset st.theLat = theLat>
    <cfset st.theLon = theLon>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(SESSION.latLon, st)>
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Then, right at the top under the first declaration of `map`, I added this `cfloop`

```
    <cfif IsDefined('SESSION.latLon')>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(SESSION.latLon)#" index="i">
            <cfoutput>
            var jsonObj = new google.maps.LatLng(#SESSION.latLon[i].theLat#, #SESSION.latLon[i].theLon#);

            var marker#i# = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: jsonObj,
                draggable: true,
                raiseOnDrag: false,
                title: "Drag me to change shape",
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("../admin/measure-vertex.png", new google.maps.Size(9, 9), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(5, 5))
            });

            measure.mvcLine.push(jsonObj);
            measure.mvcPolygon.push(jsonObj);

            measure.mvcMarkers.push(marker#i#);

            var latLngIndex#i# = measure.mvcLine.getLength() - 1;

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker#i#, "mouseover", function() {
                marker#i#.setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage("../admin/measure-vertex-hover.png", new google.maps.Size(15, 15), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(8, 8)));
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker#i#, "mouseout", function() {
                marker#i#.setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage("../admin/measure-vertex.png", new google.maps.Size(9, 9), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(5, 5)));
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker#i#, "drag", function(evt) {
                measure.mvcLine.setAt(latLngIndex#i#, evt.latLng);
                measure.mvcPolygon.setAt(latLngIndex#i#, evt.latLng);

            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker#i#, "dragend", function() {
                if (measure.mvcLine.getLength() > 1) {
                    measureCalc();
                }
            });

            if (measure.mvcLine.getLength() > 1) {

                if (!measure.line) {

                    measure.line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        map: map,
                        clickable: false,

                    });

                }

                if (measure.mvcPolygon.getLength() > 2) {

                    if (!measure.polygon) {

                        measure.polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                            clickable: false,
                            map: map,
                            strokeColor: "##FF0000",
                            strokeOpacity: 1,
                            strokeWeight: 3,
                            paths: measure.mvcPolygon
                        });

                    }

                }

            }

            if (measure.mvcLine.getLength() > 1) {
                measureCalc();
            }
            </cfoutput>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
```

Which sorted my problem out just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you create a login system and store everything in a database? If you don't have the capacity to do that, you can look at HTML5's local storage.

Here is a tutorial: 
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: Ah, I save the Longitude and Latitude values, thats not the issue. The Lon/Lat just target the building that the person draws their area on. I need to remember the **area drawing plots**, not the Lon/Lat. Unless your telling me I can use this to save the area drawing plots too; if so, how do I manage that one.  

*E: Furthermore, I want to stay away from HTML5 as this needs to be as universal as possible.*

*`EE: I've updated my question with a bit more clarification, if that helps`*

Comment: If you only need to cache the positions in a page session (and there is not an actual refresh), you can store them in a JavaScript Object.

If you need to keep the positions between page refreshes, you'll have to use a server side database solution.

Apologies, if I'm not understanding your problem...

Comment: Hi Tim, no, you understand my question just fine! It's *getting* the values out to post to the database thats the problem.